# Best books for starting with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I work a lot with PHP and have used django/python quite a bit and want to get started with Rails.

Can anyone recommend any good books for Rails to get started with?

Comment: Sorry I'm aware of the difference and use a multitude of frameworks for PHP. I also use Django which is a Python framework and found it better to learn the framework which in turn helped me to learn the language. I was just giving my background. Thanks for your insightful feedback

Answer (score 2):

[Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) from Pragmatic bookshelf has always been a very good book to start with Rails. You may need to go through the [Programming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9) book for Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely do a little bit of ruby. You have a programmer background, so the basics are pretty obvious, but you should familiarize yourself with blocks/procs/loops/iteration and symbols. After that i'd recommend that Agile Web Development with Rails, or Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.

Answer (score 0):

I find Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) to be fantastic (http://amzn.to/pANzzL). Also, if you don't want to spend much money, it's [available for free online](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). He also keeps the online version up to date with any changes in Rails framework (e.g., Rails 3.1, which is very new, has a chapter online that isn't in the print edition).

Also, the previous answers are correct, Rails is a framework, Ruby is a language. That said, I don't think starting with a book on Ruby, then moving on to Rails is the way to go. You can teach yourself what Ruby you need to get by as you learn Rails and then, later on, pick up an actual Ruby book and get a firmer grasp of the language.

Answer (score 0):

To get started with rails:

1. [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)
2. [Peepcode screencasts](http://peepcode.com/)
3. [Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)
4. [Ryan Bates screencasts](http://railscasts.com/)

To study about ruby:

1. Programming Ruby
2. The Ruby Programming Language